# Read Timed Out : sychronous query via Bigquery java API

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using the big query JAVA API to retrieve results for our analytics reporting frontend. We are trying to retrieve the results synchronously. A lot of times we get **Read timed out** error, even before the query timeout as specified in the parameters. Here's the stack trace for a sample fail:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:787)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:697)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:640)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

I am not able to retrieve the job id of the resulting job as the error occurs before I can retrieve a *JobReference* object. The timeout specified in this case was 300 sec. The query failed well before it. The query contains three JOIN's and several GROUP EACH BY clauses. Can you suggest us a possible way to debug this ?

Adding the code snippet:

```
        QueryRequest queryInfo = new QueryRequest().setQuery(sql)
                .setTimeoutMs(timeOutInSec * 1000);

        // get project id
        BQGameConnectionDetails details = Config
                .getBQConnectionDetails(gameId);
        String projectId = details.getProjectId();
        Bigquery.Jobs.Query queryRequest = getInstance(gameId).jobs()
                .query(projectId, queryInfo);
        QueryResponse response = queryRequest.execute();
```

Comment: Could you add the snippet of the code?

Comment: Added the code snippet.

Comment: How long does this query take in the BigQuery Console,  https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two timeouts involved. The first timeout is in the HTTP request you've sent to bigquery. The second is in the bigquery request timeout. It sounds like you've set the latter to a large value, but the former is likely the timeout that you're hitting. If the HTTP request times out before the BigQuery timeout, the connection will be closed and BigQuery won't have a chance to respond.

There are two options: First is to increase the HTTP request timeout (which depends on the libraries you're using, but this page [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) may be helpful). The second is to *decrease* the bigquery timeout. This means you'll have to use jobs.getQueryResults() to read the actual results, but this is a more robust method because it doesn't matter how long the query takes, you can just call getQueryResults() in a loop. I would post a link to a good java sample that does this, but I don't know that one exists, unfortunately.

Comment: I have set http timeout to 3 minutes and query timeout to 2 minutes and I still get same exception - `new GoogleCredential.Builder() .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport()) .setRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer() { override def initialize(request: HttpRequest): Unit ={ request.setConnectTimeout(60000) request.setReadTimeout(180000) } })`
 Query timeout - `new QueryRequest().setQuery(query).setTimeoutMs(120000)`